# PHP export excel working in Chrome and IE but in Firefox (Get file with no extension)

Tags: php, cross-browser, export-to-excel

My code works in Chrome and IE perfectly but when I try to download the file using Firefox it has no extension. I already tried different solutions given in stackoverflow with the same problem of mine but nothing works. Is there anybody who can help me with this?

this is my PHP code:

```
function empsal_to_excel(){
        $empsal = $_SESSION['empsalParam'];
        $rows = $this->SalaryReport->getBranchSalary($empsal['branch']);

        $numrows = count($rows); 

        // Send Header
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");;
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Employee Salary Report:".$_SESSION['comp_name'].".xls "); // à¹à¸¥à¹‰à¸§à¸™à¸µà¹ˆà¸à¹‡à¸Šà¸·à¹ˆà¸­à¹„à¸Ÿà¸¥à¹Œ
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

        // XLS Data Cell

        $this->xlsBOF(); 
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(1,3,$_SESSION['comp_name']);
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(4,0,"REPORT TITLE : ");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(4,1,"Employee Salary Report");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(4,6,"REPORT PRINT DATE : ");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(4,7, date('Y-m-d'));

        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,0,"EMPLOYEE NO.");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,1,"EMPLOYEE NAME");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,2,"JOB DESCRIPTION");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,3,"DEPARTMENT");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,4,"BRANCH");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,5,"SHIFTING SCHEDULE");          
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,6,"SALARY FREQUENCY");
        $this->xlsWriteLabel(7,7,"SALARY");

        $xlsRow = 9;

        $t=0;
        $to_log=array();
        while($t<$numrows){
            $y=0;
            foreach($rows[$t] as $key=>$items){
                $to_log[]=$key."=>".$items;
                $this->xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,$y,$items);    
                $y++;                           
                }
            $xlsRow++;
            $t++;
        }

        $this->xlsEOF();
        $this->_audittrailbase->_log('EXPORT_TO_EXCEL', 'Report' ,$to_log,null,$_SESSION['branch']);
        exit();
    }
    function xlsBOF() { 
            echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);  
            //return; 
        } 

        function xlsEOF() { 
            echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00); 
           // return; 
        } 

        function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) { 
            echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0); 
            echo pack("d", $Value); 
            //return; 
        } 

        function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value ) { 
            $L = strlen($Value); 
            echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L); 
            echo $Value; 
        //return; 
        }
```